# In C#, how can I select the correct overload based on a generic argument?

Tags: c#, generics, overload-resolution, c#-10.0

```
// overloads
void f(int x){}
void f(float x){}

// generic
void s<T>(T t){
  f(t); // <<< cannot convert from 'T' to 'int'
}

// use
s(10);
```

The C# compiler responds that, in the body of `s<T>`, I `cannot convert from 'T' to 'int'`.  Is there another way to bridge the generic -> overload gap?

(I'm on C# 10)

Comment: in which C#/dotnet? ...  is T numeric only?

Comment: From c# 11 onwards generic math is allowed other than that you need some workarounds for that.

Comment: [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73744669/what-is-are-the-best-way-to-handle-primitive-type-polymorphism-in-c/73745095#73745095) not exactly but you should get the point

Comment: @Selvin I'm using C# 10 (.NET 6, on linux), and in this case we have numbers only.

Comment: [for static methods](https://dotnetfiddle.net/R7NyUt)

Comment: `|         IfM | 0.4773 ns | 0.0170 ns | 0.0159 ns |` `| ExpressionM | 2.1410 ns | 0.0626 ns | 0.0585 ns |` so my solution is 5 times slower than Marc answer ... but of course you don't need to write all this if

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key driver for generics is doing *basically the same thing* with all `T`; calling different methods per `T` is the opposite of that; there are ways to do it, but that isn't necessarily optimal. With C# 11, you *may* be able to use generic math support if your `f` operations are mathematical. Other than that, it comes down to type testing.

Oddly, this isn't as inefficient as it looks:

```cs
void s<T>(T t){
  if (typeof(T) == typeof(int)) {
    f(Unsafe.As<T, int>(ref t));
  }
  else if (typeof(T) == typeof(float)) {
    f(Unsafe.As<T, float>(ref t));
  }
  else {
    // something
  }
}
```

because the JIT (on modern runtimes) is per-T for all value-type T, *and* will erase unreachable code. Other than that, you're down to `dynamic`:

```cs
f((dynamic)t);
```

That *is* inefficient - it involves boxing and reflection.

Comment: In conclusion: the only way to bridge the generic <-> overload gap is by writing switching code for all supported types (explicitly or using reflection).

Comment: @xtofl yes; *before generic operator support* (in very recent C#) selecting different overloads by necessity requires type switching, which can be done in explicit code or via reflection/ref-emit which ultimately just does the same at runtime; generic operator support (and abstract static members more generally) is a very different approach, which bridges this gap natively *for some scenarios*. Note that another approach is a "provider/registration" approach with polymorphism, i.e. if you have `Provider<T>.Whatever` and register `Provider<int>.Whatever = new Int32Provider()` etc

Comment: @xtofl with the obvious pitfall that if you do `Provider<T>.Whatever` with `T=Foo`, and nobody has registered a `Provider<Foo>`, then it will blow up at runtime

Answer (score 2):

The answer on your question is "depended". Depended on what you're trying to achieve.

If you need something like "If it's `int` or `double` then use this logic else use common logic" then you should do something like

```
void Foo(int value) { /* int logic */ }
void Foo(double value) { /* double logic */ }
void Foo<T>(T value) { /* common logic */ }
```

If you need something like "Here is value with generic type. Do some things and then call specific logic if it's `int` or `double`" then you should do something like

```
void Foo(int value) {}
void Foo(double value) {}
void SomeFunc<T>(T value) 
{
    switch (value)
    {
        case int intValue:
            Foo(intValue);
            break;
        case double doubleValue:
            Foo(doubleValue);
            break;
    }
}
```

But you should remember that the second code sample will box and unbox argument value. **Marc Gravell** suggested more efficient way to cast, but this is harder to read too. It's your decision what do you need exactly. More readable or more efficient code.

Comment: something of particular note: this doesn't just box *once* - it boxes *lots of times* - I count 4 [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBLANgHwAEAmAAgA1SBvAWAChCVSAxCCACmwDsNSA3AIa4ArjACU1AL71GLNuwAmEYcFwx+Q0RKrSGTAMoQAtjEIBWADwAVAHzsrGkeNL1adUh9IBnAO7YMYAAWpOyCTmL0ntSRUZ5gAl7q3LzJAGqaMCAxsbGsHGkZYgDc2TmewLACANYl7mXxiaRKKmpNyqow6U5ZdWWeeYrtal1atX1RFTDVY566c0A==) - interestingly, using `switch ((object?)value)` fixes that down to just once