# Best way to use += (add and assign) and -= (subtract and assign) operators on generic type without having to check for type

Tags: c#, generics, operator-overloading, operators

My application uses objects of type `Tag<T>` where the Tag property `Value` is of type `T`. The application interprets a custom script language into C#. I can assign Tag Value after the interpretation when the exact type of the Tag is known:

```
Tag<int> myTag = new Tag<int>();
myTag.Value += 10; //this works
```

However, I would like to encapsulate all the value assignment methods into a layer above, before the interpretation happens. At that point, the tag type is unknown (generic). Therefore I would like to assign values before knowing the exact tag type:

```
Tag<T> myTag = new Tag<T>();
myTag.Value += 10; //this doesn't : CS0019  C# Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'
```

Of course, `+=` and `-=` only work for certain types like `int` and `string`. So, I would have to add a `switch` or `if` and then decide what operator to use based on the type. But this seems like a brute force workaround and doesn't really satisfy me. Is there maybe a more elegant workaround or a best practice?

I tried googling but the [closest answer I could find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390900/cant-operator-be-applied-to-generic-types-in-c) is for the operator `==`

```
public bool Compare<T>(T x, T y) 
{ 
    return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(x, y); 
}
```

I am expecting something along these lines.

Comment: "But this seems like a brute force workaround" Well, that only indicates that generics aren't the correct thing here. There's nothing *generic* when you switch on only a few specific types. Unless you have some common generic base-class (between int and string), there's nothing *generic* here at all.

Comment: do you only want a generic add-operator for number-like types or strings as well? Because as mentioned before there's nothing common between numbers and strings, so you'd need to implement special checks for strings anyway.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain I do actually want it to cover string as well as numbers. At the very least I could separate it into two different cases: numbers vs non-number as opposed having to define a case for every single data type that C# accepts.

Comment: then the closest you will get is what Marc answered, adding a second method for strings.

Answer (score 0):

In C# 11 / .NET 7:

```cs
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Foo(1,5,3)); // 2
    }
    static T Foo<T>(T x, T y, T z) where T : INumber<T>
    {
        return (x + y) / z;
    }
```

Comment: and what about string? OP mentioned those as well. I'd assume generics aren't the correct thing here.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain `System.String` doesn't implement any suitable interfaces, so: no new options there; you could special-case it though

Comment: but this seems to be what OP is asking about. I'm well aware that strings are no maths.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain well, `string` doesn't implement `-=` which OP mentions; but again: *you can special-case* - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74742483/in-c-how-can-i-select-the-correct-overload-based-on-a-generic-argument/74742593#74742593

Answer (score 0):

While overloaded operators are always static in C# (and [here it is explained why](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/why-are-overloaded-operators-always-static-in-c)), we have to declare them specifically for all your custom types:

```
public class MyType
{
    public static MyType operator +(MyType a, MyType b)
    {
        // some logic for + operation
        return something;
    }
}
```

So now you are free to use it as usual:

```
MyType a = new();
MyType b = new();
var c = a + b;
```