# Is it possible to leverage polymorphism from within a generic method in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism

```
string Foo(string key, string defaultValue)
{
    return Lookup(key);
}

bool Foo(string key, bool defaultValue)
{
    return bool.Parse(Lookup(key));
}

T Bar<T>(string key, T defaultValue)
{
    return Foo(key, defaultValue);
}
```

The above generates an error: cannot convert from 'T' to 'string'. Presumably this is because of the order in which the compiler tackles the code, but it seems counterintuitive for it to validate a generic without waiting to find out how it is used. Is there any way around this? Thanks.

(NB: This is a simplified example. In the actual code, Bar is doing useful stuff, not just being a pointless generic wrapper around polymorphism)

EDIT: Managed to sort of break C# pursuing this:

```
class Parser<T>
{
    public static Parser<T> inst = new Parser<T>();

    public virtual T _Parse(string input)
    {
        return default(T);
    }

    public static T Parse(string input)
    {
        return inst._Parse(input);
    }
}

class ParserInt : Parser<int>
{
    public override int _Parse(string input)
    {
         return int.Parse(input);
    }   
}
```

Does not yield the expected result!

Comment: What if you call `Bar` with any type that can't be implicitly converted to any of your overloads? for this example, if `T` is a `TimeSpan`, or `List`, or even `Object` - What overload would you expect to be chosen?

Comment: In theory some stuff can be done (though it will not be "generic") but bigger question is what if somebody will call `Bar("foo", 1)`?

Comment: `Foo` is not making use of `defaultValue` at all. Is this a typo?

Comment: you can always go with switch/match pattern  on `defaultValue`'s type

Comment: Generics (and resolving of what overload of a method to call) are compile time things. So what overload of Foo is called is determined when compiling not magic that happens at runtime. If you need to call different overloads here you need to call them explicitly (explicitly converting to string when you know you want the string version of Foo for example).

Comment: ... like [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/e9XpOC) ... if you don't wana add types to the swtich by yourself you can use expressions [like this ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73744669/what-is-are-the-best-way-to-handle-primitive-type-polymorphism-in-c/#answer-73745095) (its about Converter.Convert but you could do somthing similar)

Comment: No need to call `Foo()` from `Bar<T>()`. Instead it could a receive a 3rd parameter `Func<string, T>` that converts the result of `Lookup()` to `T` on its own.

Comment: in fact there is no need to call for `Bar<T>` ... you can simply call `Foo` ... unless you have wana call this like `object s = "thestring"; var ret = Bar("key", s)` then using generics doesn't make sens because variable `ret` will always have type `object` (variable type! not type of the object inside this variable!)

Comment: Polymorphism is about substituting a (concrete) base class or interface type with a more specific (concrete) type but the question is about how to treat (non-concrete) generic types as concrete types. Btw, @Selvin's posted example is good, just 2 comments on that: 1.) The runtime is actually smart enough to avoid boxing for the `(T)(object)someValueType` cast, and 2.) For _value types_ the JIT compiler eliminates the impossible branches in Release build so it can be alright to add many cases. This is not the case for reference types though, which share the same compiled code.

Comment: "Generics (and resolving of what overload of a method to call) are compile time things. So what overload of Foo is called is determined when compiling not magic that happens at runtime." - Yes, I know. Any attempted usage of Bar could be validated at compile time, just as attempts to call Foo() would be matched to the appropriate polymorphism, or rejected.

"Foo is not making use of defaultValue at all." - It's a truncated example. 'defaultvalue' serves as both a default value and a means for C# to identify the appropriate polymorphism (since it can't do so based on return type)

Comment: "What if you call Bar with any type that can't be implicitly converted to any of your overloads? for this example, if T is a TimeSpan, or List, or even Object - What overload would you expect to be chosen?" - I would expect it to generate a compile error within Bar, just as it would if I called Foo() directly with an unsupported parameter type from anywhere else in code.

Answer (score 0):

> The above generates an error: cannot convert from 'T' to 'string'. Presumably this is because of the order in which the compiler tackles the code

No, the order does not matter.

In c# the compiler need to ensure that the generic type parameter can be substituted with *any* compatible type. This ensures that generic types can be distributed in libraries. Actual machine code is only generated by the jitter, and you do not want the jitter to give runtime errors, you want all validation to be done when compiling the source.

What would you expect `Bar("key", 0.1d)` to do? It can clearly not work, so it should generate a compile time error. But having the compiler inspect the actual method implementation is really difficult and potentially time consuming.

So the solution is to explicitly tell the compiler what types can be used with a generic method. I.e. [Generic constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint).

```
void Foo(IMyInterface value) { }

void Bar<T>(T value) where T : IMyInterface
{
    Foo(value);
}
```

This works, but the applications are somewhat limited. You cannot use generic restrictions with primitive types like in your example. Nor could you resolve methods based on the generic type, at least not without runtime type checking.  You could however call a virtual method on `IMyInterface`, if that is the goal.

So, c# generics is great for various types of collections, where you do not care at all what the type is. It can be used for other stuff, like allowing the compiler to generate specialized code for a specific type. But you should probably think a bit extra if it is the best solution. I sometimes see overuse of generics, where regular code with polymorphism provide an overall simpler solution.

As a contrast, C++ templates only need to work with types actually used by the code. But this means that templates need to be distributed as header files. There is no way to create a compiled library with template types. Templates are also (unintentionally) Turing complete, and because of this you cannot know if the compilation will ever finish. And templates do tend to cause long compilation times and poor error messages.

If the overall goal is to make calls that depend on multiple types, see [Multiple dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch). There is no builtin support for this (other than 'dynamic'), but you can use the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) as a workaround.

Comment: "In c# the compiler need to ensure that the generic type parameter can be substituted with any compatible type. This ensures that generic types can be distributed in libraries." - Nothing I've attempted to do here changes that. A generic that calls any other functions or makes use of any other class cannot be distributed without those functions or classes anyway.

About the order it tackles the code: if the compiler waited until it found an invokation of Bar before checking whether it could find a matching Foo, the code would compile. So it DOES matter what order it's doing things.

Comment: @Peeling If the compiler waited until it can find an invocation of Bar, then either Bar cannot be invoked from a dynamically linked library, or you would get runtime errors if Bar is invoked with a type that does not have a matching Foo. The source->CIL compiler does not and cannot know all the places a public method is called from, that information is just not available until all the code has been jitted.

Comment: How is it any different from having a limited set of polymorphisms of Foo in a dynamically linked library? EXACTLY the same constraints are in force.

Comment: (Incidentally, I managed to break C# pursuing this. See OP edit for details :)

Comment: @Peeling No. Polymorphism is resolved in runtime, but does not affect the interface of the class, so you can safely derive from classes all you want. *Operator overloading* is resolved at compile time, but then all the types are known, both the overloading candidates and the type you are calling with. Unless you use Generics ofc, and then you need to specify restrictions.

Comment: @Peeling Also, this discussion is fairly academical, since this is just not how c# works. If C# does not do what you expect it to, then your expectations are most likely wrong. At some point you just need to read the language specification and follow it. If you disagree with the decisions you can always make your own language.